# installing data.table results in "there is no package"

Tags: r

I am new to R and have to install a `data.table` into my workfile.
Right now, I have implemented:

```
install.packages("data.table")
require(data.table)
```

However, when I run this part (Ctrl + Enter) I get the following error in the console-window:

> Loading required package: data.table
>
> Warning message:
>
> In `library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,`  : there is no package called `data.table`

Is this truly an error or can I work on it further without problems?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: yes that's truly an error. What error do you get when you run `install.packages("data.table")`

Comment: The error message indicates that the package has not been installed. Are you sure that you evaluated *both* lines with Ctrl-Enter? During installation of the package, R should produce multiple lines of output. If you haven't seen that output, `install.packages()` has probably not run.

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to install things at work?

Comment: I have selected both lines (install.packages("data.table") require(data.table) and then pressed ctrl+enter

Comment: Complete output in console window is the following:

Comment: Try downloading the package from CRAN, put it in your library and install it. IT at your workplace most likely blocked the direct access.

Comment: MY OUTPUT: ![Image](http://imageshack.com/a/img921/7942/5VxwYL.png).

Comment: This sounds like you have no internet connection.

Comment: I am on internet since I am able to be on StackOverflow site?!

Comment: could it be that one of my configurations doesn't allow RStudio to use internet or something?

Comment: Based on the image you posted, it looks like something is going wrong when attempting to connect to the RStudio CRAN mirror. You could try selecting a different mirror -- run `chooseCRANmirror()`, select a mirror close to you, and then run your code again.

Comment: Also try picking a server that is not https.

Answer (score 27):

This solved the issue for me:

```
install.packages("data.table", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Comment: While executing that code choose no `n` if it asks `Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?`

Comment: @Tdebeus Not installing from sources that need compilation did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

If `install.packages("data.table")` does not work, try installing the binary:

`install.packages("data.table", type = "binary")`

as explained [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-installing-packages-on-r-3-5-1-running-on-mac-os-x-10-13-sierra/14758/4).